# " insert into select " query in korma

Tags: sql, postgresql, korma, sqlkorma

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers;
```

**customer table has other columns also except those "CustomerName" and "Country"**

This is my simple sql query.

Please help me to write it in KORMA SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can to that almost the same as the sql:

```
; assuming that you already define entities, customer, suppliers
(insert customers
  (values (select suppliers
                  (fields :suppliername :country))))
```